# JSON response optimization

Tags: javascript, php, json, apache

When returning a json object which contains a large number of objects which each have the same property names, do those names contribute much to a larger response size, or will apache's compression de-duplicate the names

in other words, do "name", "height", "width" strings in the below object contribute significantly to the overall size of the response?

```
{
    "object1": {
    "name" : "fred1",
    "height" : 1,
    "width" : 2
    },
    "object2": {
    "name" : "fred2",
    "height" : 1,
    "width" : 2
    },
    "object3": {
    "name" : "fred3",
    "height" : 1,
    "width" : 2
    },
    "object4": {
    "name" : "fred4",
    "height" : 1,
    "width" : 2
    },
    "object5": {
    "name" : "fred5",
    "height" : 1,
    "width" : 2
    },
    "object6": {
    "name" : "fred6",
    "height" : 1,
    "width" : 2
    }   
}
```

If so, should I return a mapping of name to index and then just send them as a normal array?

Comment: Even if they change the size, it's likely going to be a negligible difference.

Comment: if your apache gzip's the responses, then "no" ... so, basically, look at the headers

Comment: use compression and you can be as verbose as possible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

gzip compression should reduce the size a lot.
If you really want to find out how much, you could use [Charles proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com). It will tell you the compression ratio in percentage.

Btw if you need an easy to use response mapping package for PHP, you can use the [Marshal serializer](https://github.com/Kingson-de/marshal-serializer).